# Full Ubuntu Install

Tags: system-installation

I have an old computer(only 512mb RAM) which i would like to totally dedicate to Ubuntu o.s
I plan to use it to explore development and such like, what would I have to do to completely erase the system i have on it now and fully install Ubuntu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the installation media (USB or DVD) all you have to do is boot from the media and choose install Ubuntu and it should go through the install steps.

With your ram you might want to run Lubuntu or Xubuntu. I'm pretty sure that Ubuntu needs at least 1gb of ram.

Comment: I think i just might, I just basically trying to utilize this one I brought back to life. I'll download the either the X or L and try one of those but I've got a copy of the 12 so I was just wondering if it was worth a shot.  Thanks Much.

Comment: It's definitely worth a shot. If it doesn't work then you are only out about 30 minutes of time and if it does you have a project computer.

Answer (score 0):

512MB of RAM is no good for graphical installations. Consider upgrading the RAM to at least 2GB and you will love using Ubuntu. Also, when you have the CD installer, just boot it up and follow the screen instructions. Choose the option to erase all DATA and Ubuntu installer will take care the rest.

Comment: Comp, is very old, wish I could but that's the maximum for the old bird. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps Darik's  Boot Nuke (http://www.dBan.org) to clean the hard drive. 
And install ubuntu server 32 bit from a live CD or USB. 
(http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server)